# How to allow "interleaved" option-value pairs in python argparse parsers?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python script which is part of a C++ build system -- it reads C++ files and uses `libclang` to extract some metadata which gets stored as json somewhere.

We use this tool a lot with some very large files. We would like to be able to use it with `ccache`. To do that, the python script needs to "look like" `gcc` on the command line, close enough that `ccache` can just think of it as some highly nonstandard c compiler that happens to produce json instead of object code. (We are already passing it a lot of c-compiler flags anyways that need to go through to `libclang`.)

Because we had to change the way it was parsing its arguments, I changed it away from using `argparse` because I didn't know how to do what I needed using `argparse`. The question is whether there's a clever way I didn't think of / didn't know about to do this more pythonically.

---

The tool needs to parse an input filepath and an output filepath from the command line. The output filepath is signaled using `-o`, and the input filepath can be signaled using `-c`. (Sort of like how `gcc` works...) All other flags should be collected in another list, which will be forwarded to `libclang`.

Example:

```
./args.py foo bar -o baz -c qaz
   input: qaz
   output: baz
   parser_args: ['foo', 'bar']

./args.py foo bar -c qaz -o baz
   input: qaz
   output: baz
   parser_args: ['foo', 'bar']
```

The wrinkle is that it also needs to support a strange ordering in which the `-o` option appears between `-c` and the parameter to `-c`.

```
./args.py foo bar -c -o baz qaz
   input: qaz
   output: baz
   parser_args: ['foo', 'bar']
```

---

Here is the parser that I whipped up in naive (admittedly C-ish) python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def help():
    print """
    This tool takes command line arguments in a way compatible with gcc. This is
    so that it can be compatible with ccache.

    Pass with -c the path to the rtdv file.
    Pass with -o the output path to the json file.
    All other args are forwarded to libclang.


    To accomodate ccache, the following syntax is also allowed:
      -c -o output input
"""


def parse_cl_args(argv):
    input = False
    output = False
    parser_args = []

    i = 1
    while i < len(argv):
        # When we see -c, go into a mode where next parameter is the source file,
        # except that -o and its argument are allowed to appear inbetween
        if argv[i] == '-c':
            i+=1
            # Consume any -o immediately after -c
            while argv[i] == '-o':
                if output:
                    raise Exception("Too many output files specified: " + output + " , " + argv[i+1])
                output = argv[i+1]
                i+=2

            # Consume -c parameter as input file
            if input:
                raise Exception("Too many input files specified: " + input + " , " + argv[i])
            input = argv[i]
            i+=1
        elif argv[i] == '-o':
            if output:
                raise Exception("Too many output files specified: " + output + " , " + argv[i+1])
            output = argv[i+1]
            i+=2
        else:
            parser_args += [argv[i]]
            i+=1

    return (input, output, parser_args)

def main():
    if '-h' in sys.argv or '--help' in sys.argv or len(sys.argv) <= 1:
         help()
         return

    (input, output, parser_args) = parse_cl_args(sys.argv)

#    if not input:
#        sys.stderr.write('Argv: ' + str(sys.argv) + '\n')
#        raise Exception("Must use -c flag to specify input file to parse.")
#
#    if not output:
#        sys.stderr.write('Argv: ' + str(sys.argv) + '\n')
#        raise Exception("Must use -o flag to specify output path for json")

    print 'input: ', input
    print 'output: ', output
    print 'parser_args: ', parser_args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Is there a nice way to do something like this using `argparse`?

My attempt with argparse was along the lines:

1. Use a subparser for `-c` and add a `-o` option to it
2. Add a `-o` option to the top level parser also. Try to make both versions of `-o` assign to the same variable.
3. Use `parse_known_args` to collect the unmatched `parser_args`.

The problem with this is that I'm not sure how to actually configure the subparser for `-c` in this strategy. Once I've named the subparser `-c` I can add the `-o` option to it, but I'm not sure how to make it collect the token it's supposed to associate with `args.c`. It's also unclear to me from the docs how that will interact with `parse_known_args`.

Anyways the end result doesn't have to be identical to the code example I gave. It's okay for instance if only arguments that appear before `-c` and `-o` get collected as `parser_args` and others get discarded or something.

It only *really* needs to work in ways that `ccache` will invoke it. It would be nice if the help that argparse would generate is understandable.

Comment: "the input filepath can be signaled using -c. (Sort of like how gcc works" - wait, what? That's not what `-c` means to GCC. [`-c` means compile but don't link.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c-77)

Comment: I think you got mixed up and thought the file argument was an argument for `-c`. The `-c` option and the input file aren't connected at all. If you don't try to treat them as connected, I think your entire problem goes away.

Comment: Why is `ccache` passing corrupted arguments like this?

Comment: @user2357112 I know thats not really the meaning of `-c` but then how should I identify the input file in python? Just assume its the last one? What if its before -o?

Comment: Depends on what the rest of your command line looks like and how capable you are of parsing the rest of it. Tying it to `-c` doesn't sound like a good idea, though. I question the idea of whether ccache should be involved at all.

Comment: Well, I tested it quite a bit and it speeds up our rebuilds significantly. Parsing stuff with `libclang` can be expensive. I think I'm going to take your idea of not making `-c` an option and just assuming the last unknown arg is the input file. I don't know why I didn't do it that way in the first place. Gonna see how well it works now.

Comment: @user2357112: I would accept one of your comments as an answer